# Are the No Free Lunch Theorems Useful for Anything?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, search

I have been thinking about the [No Free Lunch (NFL) theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) lately, and I have a question which probably every one who has ever thought of the NFL theorems has also had. I am asking this question here, because I have not found a good discussion of it anywhere else.

The NFL theorems are very interesting theoretical results which do not hold in most practical circumstances, because a key assumption of the NFL theorems is rather strong. This assumption is, roughly speaking, that the performance of an algorithm is averaged over all problem instances drawn from a uniform probability distribution. In realistic applications the problems an algorithm typically encounters are NOT drawn from a uniform distribution, and are instead drawn from what is likely a very interesting and complicated distribution specific to the general problem setting.

So, while the NFL theorems are quite interesting results, do they have any practical implications? Or are they merely theoretical results?

Comment: It is a meta-heuristic.  I like to rephrase it as "there are no silver bullets" in the sense that every tool has places where it is the "local best" and other places where it is the worst.  No single tool, not even the human mind, is the best tool for every problem.  This necessitates the cultivation of a toolbox of approaches, and an openness to any novel, but certifiably useful, tools for the toolbox.